# Retrieve model with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I am returning data to the model and then I recover it with JS but I see that they come in Null, I add my code where I recover the data and where I send it

C#

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string type, int value)
    {
        CascadingModelGastos model = new CascadingModelGastos();
        switch (type)
        {
            case "ProyectoID":
                model.Recurso = PopulateDropDown("SELECT Id, Descripcion FROM [dbo].[Cat_Cuenta_Recurso] ", "Descripcion", "Id");
                break;
            case "RecursoID":
                model.SubRecurso = PopulateDropDown("SELECT Id, DescripcionSubRecurso FROM [dbo].[Cat_Cuenta_SubRecurso] WHERE Id_Cuenta_Recurso = " + value, "DescripcionSubRecurso", "Id");
                break;
            case "SubRecursoID":
                model.TipoPago = PopulateDropDown("SELECT ID, DescripcionTipoPago FROM[dbo].[Cat_TipoPago] WHERE ESTATUS = 'A'", "DescripcionTipoPago", "Id");
                DataSet Tabla = new DataSet();
                Tabla = BLL.BLL.Negocio.ConaultaImporte(value);
                model.Programado = "$" + Tabla.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TotalProgramadoMensual"].ToString();
                break;
        }
        return Json(model);
    }
```

The data that returns in null is: 
`model.Programado = "$" + Tabla.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TotalProgramadoMensual"].ToString();`

So I invoke the method:

```
$("select").change(function () {

        var value = 0;
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            value = $(this).val();
        }
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../AjaxMethod",
            data: '{type: "' + id + '", value: ' + value + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var dropDownId;
                var list;
                switch (id) {
                    case "ProyectoID":
                        list = response.Recurso;
                        DisableDropDown("#RecursoID");
                        DisableDropDown("#SubRecursoID");
                        PopulateDropDown("#RecursoID", list);

                        break;
                    case "RecursoID":
                        dropDownId = "#SubRecursoID";
                        list = response.SubRecurso;
                        DisableDropDown("#SubRecursoID");
                        PopulateDropDown("#SubRecursoID", list);

                        break;
                    case "SubRecursoID":
                        dropDownId = "#TipoPagoID";
                        list = response.TipoPago;
                        DisableDropDown("#TipoPagoID");
                        PopulateDropDown("#TipoPagoID", list);
                        break;
                }

            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
        var models = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        document.getElementById("Programado").value = models.Programado;
    });
});
```

So I try to recover my model data:
`var models = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));`

The final question is: At what time can I recover my model data???

Comment: you need to continue off the promise `.ajax` returns. the raw call is executed by the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use @Html.Raw(). Instead, use below code. To explain what is different, the @Html.Raw() is run when your web server is serving the request by a View. However, in your case, you load data by ajax() which sends a request to server, the server then serves the request and send back the JSON (not a View), hence your @Html.Raw() in your view never executed.

```
$("select").change(function () {

        var value = 0;
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            value = $(this).val();
        }
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../AjaxMethod",
            data: '{type: "' + id + '", value: ' + value + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var dropDownId;
                var list;
                switch (id) {
                    case "ProyectoID":
                        list = response.Recurso;
                        DisableDropDown("#RecursoID");
                        DisableDropDown("#SubRecursoID");
                        PopulateDropDown("#RecursoID", list);

                        break;
                    case "RecursoID":
                        dropDownId = "#SubRecursoID";
                        list = response.SubRecurso;
                        DisableDropDown("#SubRecursoID");
                        PopulateDropDown("#SubRecursoID", list);

                        break;
                    case "SubRecursoID":
                        dropDownId = "#TipoPagoID";
                        list = response.TipoPago;
                        DisableDropDown("#TipoPagoID");
                        PopulateDropDown("#TipoPagoID", list);
                        break;
                }
                // TRY THIS ONE
                document.getElementById("Programado").value = response.Programado;

            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```